# How to traverse two levels up when referencing a coldfusion component in a cfinvoke?

Tags: coldfusion, path, parent, cfc

If I don't want to do any mappings, is there another way to call a method in a component, which is "two levels up". Like so:

```
  service
     component_to_call.cfc
  mem
     pages
     handlers
        calling.cfc
```

this is my call from inside `calling.cfc`:

```
  <cfinvoke 
    component="service.component_to_call"
    method="do_the"
    param1="#renderedResults#" 
    param2="#taskByName#" 
    returnvariable="tamperedCode">
    </cfinvoke>
```

which throws an error that the `service.component_to_call` can't be found.

**Qustion:**
How can I call the component in the parent folder?

Comment: Why would you not want to create mappings?

Comment: What version of CF are you using? This can have a bearing on what kind of proxy techniques you can use. I believe in CF 8 or older the technique I mentioned in my answer is actually cleaner. You can review that example in the ColdFusion Cookbook, http://www.coldfusioncookbook.com/

Comment: Using `coldfusion8`. Don't mind mappgins but can only reset anything on the server next week. So I was looking for a "weekend solution"

Comment: You know you can set mappings in Application.cfc, yeah?  You don't need to do it in CFAdmin (indeed I generally *wouldn't* set the mappings in CFAdmin).

Comment: @AdamCameron - I think I have it. The folder from which I was trying to call is using another Application.cfc without mappings, whereas my main Application.cfc (2nd one being a leftover, still not removed) includes a bunch of mappings. The error I was getting was that the "component could not be found at the path specified"

Comment: Yeah, that trips me up every now and then too ;-)

Comment: Ok. Cool. I still have another question though unrelated... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754644/how-to-add-a-pure-javascript-compiler-plugin-server-side-when-running-cfgroovy-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you want to use mappings?  That's a bit odd.

Anyway, just browse directly to the CFC you wish to instantiate, and it will output it's autogenerated API docs, the first thing will be its full dotted path.  You can use that.  However that is absolute, not relative.

What you cannot do is to somehow specify a relative path like one might with a file (eg: "../../fileInGrandparentDir.cfm"... one cannot do that with a CFC path.

An alternative is to make some directory that is an ancestor to both CFCs into a custom tag path, then you can just reference the CFCs by their filename and CF will find them.  There's a performance hit with doing this if the directory structure is complex.  That said: not *much* of a performance hit.

Really... you should have a mapping to the top level of your app's directory, and then use the mapping to fully-path the CFCs.  That's how it's generally done, and is the most transportable approach, I think.

Comment: just commented above. Actually I have a mapping to the service folder, which I'm alway referencing. Strangely though, 2 levels down, it does not work anymore. Still, thanks for the info! Always appreciated.

Comment: How are you specifying the mapping, and how is it manifesting this "not working"? *That* the the problem you ought to be addressing, rather than working around it.  Can I suggest you start another question and we can look @ sorting that out?

Comment: @AdamCameron, I would be interested in seeing the mapping fix as well since I had the same situation a while back, which led the workaround I gave.

Comment: @JamesRLamar: it's not something I can jot down here, but look @ this Gist: https://gist.github.com/3842591. Contact me off-list if you need further help (contact details in my profile).

Answer (score 3):

You could include the CFC from the level up in a Proxy.cfc that is at the same level as the calling CFC and then extend Proxy.cfc by adding extends="Proxy" as an attribute of the calling CFC.

Example Proxy.cfc

```
<cfcomponent name="Proxy">
<cfinclude template="../../service/component_to_call.cfc">
</cfcomponent>
```

Example calling cfc

```
<cfcomponent name="calling" extends="Proxy">
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: I dunno.  To me that code is an example of "just because one *can* do something doesn't mean one *should* do something". It just seems wrong.  Mileage varies though.

Comment: I try to avoid doing this too, but sometimes it is exactly what is needed